# Passing a variable from AJAX to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working on a php project.
I have an associative array which I use to make a dictionary. I have also a string with a text where are included some keys of the array. What I want to do is generating another String with the same text of the first one but where key words are replaced with array's values.

Before the sostitution I want the user writes in each empty-value of the array (which compares into the String) the contents. I have to do it throw a pop up. I need to get the variable's content of the Javascript variable and put it into the PHP array. I have tried to use AJAX but I am a biginner and I do not know if I am doing well.

Here my code (which it does not work):

```
<?php
  $array["[[red]]"] = "Once upon a time";
  $array["[[blue]]"] = "fox";
  $array["[[black]]"] = "cat";
  $array["[[orange]]"] = "";

  $string = "<br /> It has been a long time since [[red]] "
  . "[[blue]]. My name is [[blue]] "
  . "and my surname is [[black]]. <br />"
  . "My age is[[orange]]. <br /> <br />.";

  echo "First string': ". $string;
?>
<br /> <br />

<?php
  foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  {
    if ((strstr($string, $key) == true) && ($value == ""))
    {
?>
      <script>
        name = prompt("Insert a correct value: ");
        while ((name== "") || !(isNaN(name)) || name== null)
        {
          window.alert("Wrong insert!");
          name= prompt("Insert a correct value: ");
        }

        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?name="+name,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      </script>

<?php
        $q = $_REQUEST["name"];
        $value = $q;
        echo "the value is  ".$q;
    }
    //echo $key." => ".$value;
    echo "<br/> <br/>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what the problem is. Also, specify any PHP errors and JavaScript errors you get. That is: enable error reporting in PHP, and inspect the console tab of the developer tools in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a string with key words being replaced by values in your array, you can use the [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function like this:

```
$array["red"] = "Once upon a time";
$array["blue"] = "fox";
$array["black"] = "cat";
$array["orange"] = "";

$sentence = "<br />It has been a long time since %s %s. My name is %s and my surname is %s.<br /> My age is %s. <br /><br />.";
echo "First string" . sprintf($sentence, $array["red"], $array["blue"], $array["blue"], $array["black"], $array["orange"]);
```

As for the second part of your question, where you want to capture the user's inputs to fill up empty entry in the array... well, you need to first correct your `nome` js variable with `name`.

Then you need to submit both the keys and the user-provided value in your AJAX call, so that you know which entry in your associative array to update. It will be easier to capture the query parameters before your `$array` is instantiated.

Also, [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) **doesn't** return `true` even if the `needle` is present in the `haystack`. Take a look at the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).

So maybe something like:

```
<?php
  // you may want to modify the handling of the query parameters to suit your needs
  if(isset($_REQUEST['key']) && isset($_REQUEST['name'])
    $array[$_REQUEST['key']] = $_REQUEST['name'];  

  $array["red"] = "Once upon a time";
  $array["blue"] = "fox";
  $array["black"] = "cat";
  $array["orange"] = "";

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strstr($string, $key) && $value.empty()) {
?>
    <script>
      name = prompt("Insert a correct value: ");
      while ((name== "") || !(isNaN(name)) || name== null) {
        window.alert("Wrong insert!");
        name= prompt("Insert a correct value: ");
      }

      var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?name=" + name + "&key=" + <?php echo $key?>,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    </script>

<?php
    }
  }

  /* echo etc.. */
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The variable is "name", not "nome".

I think I will not change that part since it works ok (and I have to do in this way because the project is much more complex. I have just posted an example). The problem is the second part. I need to get the "name" variable and pass it to php (without refreshing the page). Then, it would be put into the array's value that was empty before.

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you a sense of how to solve it. I can't guarantee it will work to your needs. You may have to modify (especially the query parameters) to suit your problem.

Comment: Are you sure `$string = "<br /> It has been a long time since [[red]].."` actually replaces `[[red]]` with the value of `$array["[[red]]"]`?

Comment: No, it does not. I have another part of code for that purpose. It works. I have not posted it here because it makes no problem. But before executing that part I need to fill the empty values into the array. I will try the code you have posted and I will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: No, it does not work. I have the same problem. I am not able to pass the variable I get from the pop up to PHP. This piece of code, it does not work:

var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?name=" + name + "&key=" + <?php echo $key?>,true);
      xmlhttp.send();

When I try to get the varibales with $_REQUEST, there is nothing inside them.

Comment: Any error messages in your browser debugger? What http status is xmlhttp returning? Hard to tell what's wrong without those info.